# Python - Scrapy - Creating a crawler that gets a list of URLs and crawls them

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to create a spider with the package "Scrapy" that gets a lists of URLs and crawls them. I have searched stackoverflow for an answer but could not find something that will solve the issue.

My script is as follows:

```
class Try(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "Try"

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(Try, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.start_urls = kwargs.get( "urls" )
      print( self.start_urls )

   def start_requests(self):
      print( self.start_urls )
      for url in self.start_urls:
          yield Request( url , self.parse )

   def parse(self, response):
      d = response.xpath( "//body" ).extract()
```

When I crawl the spider:

```
Spider = Try(urls = [r"https://www.example.com"])
process = CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(Spider)
process.start()
```

I get the following info printed while printing self.start_urls:

- In the **__init__** function printed on screen is: 
  [r"https://www.example.com"] (as passed to the spider).
- In the **start_requests** function printed on screen is: None

Why do I get None? Is there another way to approach this issue? or Is there any mistakes in my spider's class?

Thanks for any help given!

Comment: use other name for list to keep urls at start - `self.start_urls` is used by `scrapy` so it can remove them. I'm wonder if you put urls in `self.start_urls` in `__init__` then maybe it will use them and you don't have to use `start_requests` ?

Comment: `process.crawl` will create a new Try object without parameters when it calls `from_crawler`. See Crawler class in Scrapy Source Code. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/crawler.py#L101-L102

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the Spider Class in `process.crawl` and pass `urls` parameters there.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request


class Try(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'Try'

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(Try, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.start_urls = kwargs.get("urls")

   def start_requests(self):
      for url in self.start_urls:
          yield Request( url , self.parse )

   def parse(self, response):
      d = response.xpath("//body").extract()

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(Try, urls=[r'https://www.example.com'])
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run

```
process.crawl(Try, urls=[r"https://www.example.com"])
```

then it send `urls` to `Try` as I expect. And even I don't need `start_requests`.

```
import scrapy

class Try(scrapy.Spider):

   name = "Try"

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Try, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.start_urls = kwargs.get("urls")

   def parse(self, response):
       print('>>> url:', response.url)
       d = response.xpath( "//body" ).extract()

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess({
'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
process.crawl(Try, urls=[r"https://www.example.com"])
process.start()
```

But if I use

```
spider = Try(urls = ["https://www.example.com"])

process.crawl(spider)
```

then it looks like it runs new `Try` without `urls` and then list is empty.